# Unable to display images from asset catalogs

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this strange error where images contained in the image assets are unable to display in the app.

The files are definitely shipped with the application since I'm able to load them into UIImages and check their size. When I attach them to an UIImageView they won't show up though. The image view is just blank!

Answer (score 0):

Setting deployment target to the latest available option solved this for me.

Comment: I posted this question and answer to help others having the same problem as me.